# Gracefully shut down javaagent when application exits

Tags: java, javaagents

I'm writing a javaagent to monitor applications. It starts up a server and displays the metrics calculated.

How do I configure my agent so that whenever the application is closed, some clean up is performed, and the agent exits? I've looked at shutdown hooks, but they require access to the main method which I do not have.

This is my premain method. I'm using Prometheus's Java library for generating the metrics, and jetty for the server itself.

```
    Server server = new Server(1234);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    // Expose Promtheus metrics.
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MetricsServlet()), "/");
    // Add metrics about CPU, JVM memory etc.
    DefaultExports.initialize();


    // Start the webserver.
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

When the application exits, the JVM does not, because my agent is holding it up. I am generating logs from the server, and would like to save whatever data I have and exit, instead of holding up the JVM. I've also looked at byte buddy to transform the main class, but can you add a shutdown hook through it? Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the threads used in the javaagent are not daemon threads. Change these as  `setDaemon(true);`

Comment: I would like to clean up resources, like saving the log before the shutdown. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: To do cleanup, you can use shutdownhook https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread).  `shutdown hooks, but they require access to the main method`  - This is wrong , you can register shutdownhook at any method before jvm shutdown process begins.